# Update property object in array state reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array Object in my state named **object**
so I have, in my state object in parent component something like:

```
object:[{id:1, name:"name"},{id:2, name:"name2"}];
```

And I have a select box in child component for **every** object in array and select is printed with **this.props.object.map** passed by props like:

```
var elements = this.state.object.map(function(element, k){
        return (

        <Components object={this.state.object} element={element} setPropertyElement={this.setPropertyElement} />         

        )
      }, this);
```

In child component I have select with **change** function like:

```
<select className="form-control" ref="name" defaultValue="j" onChange={this.change}>
   <option value="j">j</option>
   <option value="x">x</option>
</select>
```

So in this case I see in my page 2 elements with related select for change name.
I have my **function change**.

```
change(event){
   this.props.setPropertyElement(this.props.element, event.target.value);
}
```

In my parent element so I have a function **setPropertyElement**:

```
setPropertyElement(element, value){

      element.name = value;
  }
```

My question is:
My operations are correct or I'm modifing in wrong way state object?
In this case How Can I change correctly value of property object in array?

Comment: What is `this.props.element`? Is `setPropertyElement` also passed down as a prop? Please update your `<Component object={this.state.object}>` line above to reflect this.

Comment: Hello Chris, thankyou, I Edited my questions, the props.element is a element of state object passed in components by .map

Comment: What about `this.props.setPropertyElement`? It doesn't look like it's passed down as a prop from the parent to the child.

Comment: yest setPropertyElement is a method of parent passed by props I edited my question

Comment: In that case I'd say everything looks good (at a glance). This is definitely a valid way of altering the parent state from a child.

Comment: Ok, thanyou, I'm new in reactJS and I'm student, and so I have to change state property with setState({}) and use immutable when I don't pass direct element?

Comment: Always use setState when changing the state.

Comment: @LorenzoBerti immutable is not required. When you change the value somewhere in `this.state`, React does not noticed that state is changed. That's why you need a `this.setState`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are in the right direction. As you already said, to change the state, call the setState({}), where you have to give in which element are you updating. In this case, if you use the [spread operator](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes) it should be similar to this:

```
this.setState({object: [
     ...this.state.object.filter(x => element.ID !== x.ID),
     { id: element.id, name: element.name }
]})
```

Comment: Hello juncab, thanks, in your method you use rightly set state, but in my method above I don't use setState but Simply assign value to property, so why also my method is correct?

Comment: If you could update your post and add the whole code, I could tell you why it works. It's hard to tell just by seeing those pieces of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let editableComparatorIndexes = [...this.state.ids];
   editableComparatorIndexes[i] = 1;
   this.setState({editableComparatorIndexes});
```